# separar Fecha y Hora

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo la siguiente con la hora formato datetime

```
create table tabla
  (
    f_inicial date not null ,
    f_final date not null ,
    c_almacen varchar (250),
    sw_costo smallint,
    sw_consulta smallint,
    usuario char(30) not null,
    sw_genera_consulta smallint,
     ts_creacion datetime year to fraction(3)
        default current year to fraction(3)
  );
```

Necesito separar en el campo ts_creacion la fecha y la hora

```
usuario                        ts_creacion    
ct060901                       2017-06-15 10:29:00.000
ct060901                       2017-06-15 10:34:08.000
```

Answer (score 4):

Estas son algunas de las opciones que podés usar:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ts_creacion, '%Y-%m-%d') FechaStr, 
       DATE_FORMAT(ts_creacion,'%H:%i:%s')  HoraStr,
       DATE(ts_creacion)  Fecha,
       TIME(ts_creacion)  Hora
       FROM tabla
```

Comment: me genera el siguiente mensaje o error  674: Routine (date_format) can not be resolved.

Comment: No puedo reproducir tu error, me funciona correctamente, fijate [esta](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ea49/1) prueba. Estamos hablando de un mysql o de un informix?

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras pero la que yo mas utilizo es así...

```
select   LEFT((ts_creacion),10) AS fecha, RIGHT((ts_creacion),8) as hora from tabla
```

Comment: intento realizarlo de esta forma y me genera el siguiente error  674: Routine (left) can not be resolved.

Comment: Mmmm que versión de mysql esta manejando ?

Comment: MySQL Database Version 5.0.51b

Comment: pruebe con este ejemplo..   select DATE(ts_creacion) as fecha , TIME(ts_creacion) as hora from tabla

Comment: me sigue generando el mismo error al momento de sacar la hora  select DATE(ts_creacion) as fecha , TIME(ts_creacion) as hora from tabla
   674: Routine (time) can not be resolved.
No se si este bien creada la tabla si el tipo de dato es correcto o si es necesario modificarlo

Comment: Ummm asegúrese que el campo donde esta guardando la fecha sea de tipo DATE

Answer (score 0):

Que tal la funcion [HOUR(datetime)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour):

```
SELECT HOUR(ts_creacion) from tabla
```

O [TIME(datetime)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) que te lo retorna la hora, minuto y segundo:

```
SELECT TIME(ts_creacion)
```

Comment: me genera el siguiente error   674: Routine (hour) can not be resolved.