# Consulta MySQL traer pedidos Solo con distinta fecha y no que se diferencia por hora

Tags: mysql

estoy queriendo traerme datos de la base de datos, pero que éstos no se repitan si tienen mismo dia, me explico, en la base de datos guardo un pedido con fecha y hora. La fecha puede ser la misma pero la hora es distinta.

Lo que quiero hacer es que el pedido me aparezca una sola vez por fecha, y no que se repita si tiene una hora distinta, ya probé usando DISTINCT pero no funciona y no se me ocurre otra forma.

Como se ve en la foto, tengo mismas entregas repetidas 2-3 veces, pero las horas  son distintas.

Si contamos la cantidad de Entregas que hay, solamente hay dos, bueno, entonces solamente deberian verse 2 filas en la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi consulta:

```
select DISTINCT e.Entrega, p.Pedido, p.Remito, e.Fecha from Entrega e INNER JOIN Pedido p where fecha between '" + desdeFecha + " 00-00-00' and '" + hastaFecha + "24-00-00';
```

Comment: fijate en esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/79023/324

Comment: el tema es que a la fecha la hicieron como `varchar` y no como `Date`, funcionará eso?

Comment: si las transformas por supuesto.. igual, ahora que miro mejor, es un simple group by...

Comment: Si, es verdad, me di cuenta hace un ratito, era simplemente poner un GROUYP BY e.Entrega y listo

Comment: Dependiendo del origen de las variables desdeFecha y hastaFecha, este código puede ser vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Es mejor utilizar sentencias preparadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como mencionó @gbianchi en los comentarios, lo que necesitaba mi consulta era un `GROUP BY` para agrupar los resultados para cada grupo

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.Entrega, p.Pedido, p.Remito, e.Fecha 
FROM Entrega e INNER JOIN Pedido p WHERE fecha BETWEEN '" + desdeFecha + " 00-00-00' AND '" + hastaFecha + "24-00-00' 
GROUP BY e.Entrega;
```